# Generate polygons based on point origins and pre-determined polygon dimensions and orientations

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, polygon-creation

I have a shapefile with 300 origin points for polygons I want to generate. I also have a table with a record for each origin point with attributes for the desired polygon's dimensions and angle of orientation.

Can anyone help me use a script or model builder to run through the points and generate polygon shapefiles based on the existing input?

I can work in ArcGIS 10, ArcGIS Pro, or QGIS.

Comment: Please decide which desktop GIS you wan to ask about in this question and then describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Arcgis 10.

Use a arcpy.da.SearchCursor(...) to iterate over you point geometry. At this time you retrieve you x an y. After, use an Insert cursor to populate the geometry (polygon)... with your calculated offset.

```
import arcpy

gdb_path = "path_to_gdb.GDB"

name_fc_pts= "point"
name_fc_poly = "poly"

fc_pt = "{0}/{1}".format(gdb_path,name_fc_pts)
fc_poly="{0}/{1}".format(gdb_path,name_fc_poly)

if not arcpy.Exists(fc_poly):
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(gdb_path,name_fc_poly,"POLYGON",fc_pt,None,None,arcpy.SpatialReference(32198)) # you must set you projection EPSG
else:
    arcpy.TruncateTable_management(fc_poly) # to clear your previous result (optional)

cursor_poly = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc_poly, ["SHAPE@"])

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_pt, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor_pt:
    for row_pt in cursor_pt:
        pt_x = float(row_pt[0][0])
        pt_y = float(row_pt[0][1])

        print pt_x,pt_y

        array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(pt_x, pt_y),  
                 arcpy.Point(pt_x + 500, pt_y),
                 arcpy.Point(pt_x + 500, pt_y + 200)]         )
        cursor_poly.insertRow([arcpy.Polygon(array)])


    del row_pt

del cursor_poly
```

Comment: This works for me - I was hoping for a native tool, I feel like ArcGIS used to have one. I'll make this work.